# AH00027: No authentication done error after upgrading from Apache 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, apache-2.4, httpd

I recently updated Apache on Cent OS 7 from 2.2 to 2.4 and after the update I am not able to access the root folder,

I get the following error:

```
[Fri Apr 29 16:30:19.977037 2016] [core:error] [pid 32095] [client 10.211.55.1:44429] AH00027: No authentication done but request not allowed without authentication for /. Authentication not configured?
```

As mentioned [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html) in the Authorization section you can still use old directives Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy by loading the module (Which I loaded obviously):

```
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

My Directory directive is as follow:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I am not really sure what the problem might be, I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who intercepts with the same problem, the solution in my case was to add the following line in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Cent OS default directory structure, but you will want to follow something like this:

```
 <Directory />
   Require all denied
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
 </Directory>

 <Directory /PATH ON SERVER TO YOUR DOCUMENT ROOT>
   Require all granted
   AllowOverride All
   Options FollowSymLinks
 </Directory>
```

To use the Apache 2.4 directives, you will need to load `mod_authz_core`

```
 LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

If you don't have any other old (i.e. Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy) access control directives, comment out the access_compat module:

```
 #LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

If you do have other instances of the old 2.2 access control, update them if at all possible to use the Apache 2.4 [Require directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), or similar Apache 2.4 authentication directives. It is not a good idea to mix the old and the new. As noted in the documentation, "unpredictable" results can occur.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt update, I added these configuration changes and now the HTTPD is failing to start. I get the following the error while starting it:

`May 02 10:12:01 dealdays-www-1a.vagrant.loc.vag httpd[32592]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 104 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
May 02 10:12:01 dealdays-www-1a.vagrant.loc.vag httpd[32592]: Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not in...ration`
May 02 10:12:01 dealdays-www-1a.vagrant.loc.vag systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
.

Comment: BTW, the module  mod_access_compat is also loaded as mentioned here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html

Comment: If you are interested in the my conf file, you can find it here: http://pastebin.com/Yg4yh0uc

Comment: Make sure you have the module "authz_core_module" loaded.

Comment: Your install appears to use nonstandard names for modules. It looks like the `authz_core_module` is probably loaded with `LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so`

Comment: Also, if you have `apache2ctl` available, the command `apache2ctl -t` checks your configuration before attempting start/restart. Can save a lot of headaches.

Comment: Finally, in the "upgrading" document I note about 7 warnings against mixing old and new directives, ending with comment by Apache contributor "`mod_access_compat` only works if you don't mix `Allow` and `Require` directives." If you are going to upgrade, you need to upgrade, which means using the "upgrade" document to help you fix your "old" configuration files or write new ones.

Comment: @Colt thanks a lot for the help, the problem was gone when I added: `LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so` in the configuration file. I am not mixing the older directive and new directives. I am gonna stick to the older ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow apache read access;

```
 <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Should work

Comment: This allows access to the whole server. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Colt, true, your way is much better.